# How can I publish my Nuxt app in Bluehost

Tags: nuxt.js, bluehost

I want to publish my site in [Bluehost](https://www.bluehost.com/).
When I generate the production site with `yarn build`, and then accessing the `.nuxt` directory to copy all the contents to my bluehost html folder I get just plain text and not the Running site as you can see here.
[tecnoeducacion.online](http://tecnoeducacion.online)

Please tell me if there are more configuration steps before `yarn build`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yarn generate` is for SSG (`target: 'static'`), if you want to host some static files. It's basically JAMstack and hostable on Github pages/Netlify/Heroku etc.
More info here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/static-site-generation

`yarn build` is for SSR (`target: 'server'`), it requires a Node.js server and will generate all the pages on demand on the server.
More info here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/server-side-rendering

Answer (score -1):

I had to Yarn Generate, instead of Yarn build, to make it work, but would be good if anybody could explain the difference of one to the other command